# Making an Army with variations

Tags: animation, modifiers, particles, geometry, random

My goal is to create an army that marches through a landscape. if possible with one character. This character has various armor, fabrics, materials, etc.
How can I scatter this character, but with different variations, what would be an efficient way to do it?
And what would be the best way to save memory? (Geometry, Particles, Array) :)

Comment: If possible with only one Character*

Comment: There might be an add-on, but the way I would do it would be with code, changing the location of the armature positions and the characters location slightly with some randomness from the code

Comment: i would use geometry nodes with just a few characters. Then you can still vary materials and armors. Here is a tutorial in which the basics are explained: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLvE1XtiXcfOklbybsDhi44eEG72cCzc4v you can of course put in the "collection info"-node in geometry nodes different characters too - so you would have "an army" ;)

Comment: @Psyonic What codes are you talking about? Script?

Comment: @Chris I like that, but i still have to make every character with every asset, I would love if one could just put a random selection in the node setup. But yeah thx

Comment: Yeah, Python scripting, but there's probably much easier ways of doing it